# Como pasar de pagina de espera a página de datos ajax php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```js
loadin.php

<h2>Por favor espere...</h2>
 <h1>Tu peticion se esta procesando, esto puede tardar de 1-2 minutos</h1>
            <img src="<?php echo images/loader.gif'?>" id="img">



<script>

(function($){
    var i = 0;
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'conexion.php',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
            success:function(res){
                var js = JSON.parse(res);
                js.forEach(res => {
                    if (i < res.Id) {
                        i++;
                        location.href='datos_usuario';
                    }
                });
            }
    });
    
});
```

```css
<div id="kd-div-centro"><br>
      <div class="kd-div-resumen">
            <h5>Datos</h5>
            <label id="id"></label>
            <p id="edad"></p>
            <p id="info"></p>

       </div>
</div><br>
```

```html
conexion.php
$db_name = 'prueba';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_server = 'localhost';


    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    $select = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tabla");

    $resp = array();
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
        $resp [] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($resp);
```

```js
var i = 1;
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'conexion.php',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
            success:function(res){
                var js = JSON.parse(res);
                js.forEach(res => {
                    if (i == res.Id) {
                        i++;
                        location.href='pagina_de_datos';
                    }
                });
            }
    });
    
});
```

1.añado que primero esta el formulario que va a mysql y luego esos datos hace un processo con puppeteer y depues de eso puppeteer finaliza e inserta a mysql y es ese Id que quiero comparar para luego mostrar dichos datos de cada usuario correspondiente... espero ser mas claro y les agaradezco su tiempo y ayuda. de ser location.haref el que me reinicia el valor ¿que debo hacer? en este caso. creo que la pagina loadgin.php deberia ser dinamica u seria mas facil el proceso con vuejs ?
2.hay otro scritp con la misma funcionalidad de ajax que me muestra los valores en estos campos, no lo creo necesario publicar...

Comment: Al cambiar la ubicación (`location.href`) se carga una nueva página y por eso es que nunca avanza el iterador, quedándose siempre en la primera coincidencia. Se necesitan más detalles para poder sugerir algo. Recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/513856/edit) las veces que sea necesario para agregar información adicional como qué es lo que quieres hacer con los datos recibidos, tal vez agregarlos a un contenedor.

Comment: Agregué mas detalles, le agradezco su tiempo y ayuda... el otro script que comento solo me inserta la información en su debido campo. por eso no lo creo necesario publicar.

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Warren veo que no estas usando el beforeSend. Entiendo que quieres hacer que se muetres un loading o algo mientras esta haciendo la peticion ajax y cuando termine hacer otra cosa. Por eso tienes que usar el beforsend de esta manera:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'conexion.php',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
        beforeSend: function(){
            //javascript de lo que quieres realizar.
            //Por ejemplo un show de alguna capa de loading o modal...
        }
        success:function(res){
            //Javascript cuando termina el ajax.
            //Por ejemplo ocultamos la capa o el modal que hemos sacado en el beforsend
        }
});
```

Comment: Hola @Jordi Turell El loadin ya esta con su respectivo parrafo, lo que quiero es que al haber una nueva info en mysql pues que pase a la vista de datos y el iterador incremente para que asi esté encuchando para la proxima insercion... solo que me funciona a la primera el iterador no imcrementa y al hacer otra insercion me pasa automaticamente a la vista de datos de la insercion anterior... espero me entida y me oueda dar una ayuda o idea. gracias...